# log4net gmail smtp appender do not sending emails

Tags: email, gmail, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I'm trying to use SmtpAppender of log4net in order to send log via Gmail. But it's not working - I did not received any email. Internal logging didn't showed any errors, so I'm even not sure is it failed or not.
Here is config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
 <system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
   <listeners>
    <add name="tracer" 
     type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
     initializeData="D:\\Dev\\Camps\\log4net.log" />
    </listeners>
   </trace>
 </system.diagnostics>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <authentication value="Basic" />
      <username value="...@gmail.com" />
      <password value="..." />
      <to value="...@gmail.com" />
      <from value="...@gmail.com" />
      <subject value="log4net message from Camps.DAL" />
      <smtpHost value="smtp.gmail.com" />
      <port value="587"/>
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <EnableSsl value="true"/>
      <lossy value="false" />
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="ALL"/>
      </evaluator>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: If you have enabled 2FA on your gmail account, you need to create and use an app password rather than your normal password.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to use your username instead of your email address:

```
<username value="...@gmail.com" /> <<---- username, not email address
```